# C-programming ftell fseek fread, read size of a file

Tags: c, file-io, fread, fseek

I have a file. I read the size of file. Then I loop reading two bytes at a time until I get to the end of the file. After every read operation I increment the current position by 2, however the position does not get incremented after I get to half the size of the file, the fread operation will read 0 bytes.

the program reads the file size. I perform fread (2 bytes everytime) until the current position is equal to the size of the file. 
It reads 22915 byes for the file size
It increments position by 2 after every read, however when current position gets to 11459 which is half the size of the file it will read zero bytes thus going into an infinite loop.

```
FILE *file;
char *file_name;
int readCount = 0;
int position = 0;
int fileSize;
unsigned short mem_accesses;

file_name = "sample.txt";

/** open the file */
file = fopen(file_name, "rb");
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
fileSize = ftell(file);
rewind(file);


while(position<fileSize){
   mem_accesses = getNumberAccesses();
   printf("position: %d filesize: %d\n",position, fileSize);

}

unsigned short getNumberAccesses(){
/** calculate number of accesses for process */
unsigned short val;

readCount = fread(&val, sizeof(val), 2, file);

position += readCount;
printf("read count: %d\n", readCount);

return val;
}
```

Comment: I see no question here. What is your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
readCount = fread(&val, sizeof(val), 2, file);
```

This statement reads two items of two bytes each. And it returns the value **2**, for the number of items read. The second and third parameters multiplied together tell `fread` how many bytes to read.

Comment: @OP: You should have changed `...sizeof(val),2...` to `...1,sizeof(val)...`.

Answer (score 1):

fread return the number of elements read, not number of bytes.

(Incidentally, in your code you mistakenly give it an element count of 2 which causes a buffer overflow).

You should check fread's return value so you won't run into infinite loops in the case of errors.

Instead of querying for the file size, I would simply call fread (or other input functions) in a loop until the end of file.